# CImageList is changing colours when I load it from the application resources

Tags: mfc, imagelist

I am colour blind so I could be barking up the wrong tree here.

This is a BMP file that I am using for a `CImageList`:

[image: BITMAP image]

It looks colourful to me, albeit small. This is what it looks like in VS 2019 Editor:

[image: BITMAP image in VS 2019 Editor]

To me, they look the same. This is how I am creating my `CImageList` object:

```
m_imgList.Create(IDB_BMP_DIGITAL_MEDIA_LIST, 16, 10, 0x0000FF00);
```

This then gets passed into the `CListCtrl` to be used. Now, when I run my application:

[image: BITMAP in Dialog]

The colouring is no longer the same? The BMP file is 24 bit.

How do I stop this?

Comment: The image lost its colors, so it became B/W. Strange...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to do it:

```
// Create the full-color image list
m_imgList.Create(16, 16, ILC_MASK | ILC_COLOR24, 0, 0);

// Load the full-color bitmap
CBitmap bmp;
bmp.LoadBitmap(IDB_BMP_DIGITAL_MEDIA_LIST);

// Add the bitmap into the image list
m_imgList.Add(&bmp, 0x0000FF00);
```

Results:

[image: Results]